# How to disable caching of page?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching

In my web application I have a problem with the browser back button, so I used this code to disable caching,I cleared all the cache from the browser but it didn't work.

```
// Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

// Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

//Proxies
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Comment: Did you try what Kevin Biasci suggested in his answer? You can make it into one page (AJAX) application too.

And try https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=disable%20back%20button

Answer (score 0):

I know it will sound silly but try to invalidate the cache and try again (ex: CTRL-F5 in your browser).